# Direct file downloads based off file extension?

Tags: software-recommendation, directory, downloads, file-format

Is it possible to make it that whenever I download a file, it is redirected to a certain folder based on its file extension?

Eg, *.jpg, *.gif, *.png, etc, that it downloads to my pictures folder, *.mov, *.mpeg, *.wmv, etc, to movies, etc.

---

### EDIT

Possibly through google chrome extensions?

Answer (score 3):

There is a solution in **Firefox**.

[Automatic Save Folder](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/automatic-save-folder/) add-on offers such feature that allows you to specify where each file you are downloading will be saved too. After installing this add-on, go to **Tools** and select **Automatic Save Folder** to configure the options.

Also, for **Chrome**, maybe is useful this post: [Is there a Chrome extension similar to Automatic Save Folder for Firefox?](https://superuser.com/questions/207898/is-there-a-chrome-extension-similar-to-automatic-save-folder-for-firefox)

Comment: I use chrome, but that's good to know. I'm going to look in to developing an extension for it.

Comment: Source: http://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/347 (you took out some words but kept the grammatical error)

Answer (score -2):

If you are meaning to use wget in this instance, it is possible to just add another parameter to the command.

```
wget example.com/file.png /home/foobar/png/
```

If you are meaning to use any  medium whatsoever such as a mixture of wget, a web browser, etc. Then no. It wouldn't be possible without a directory-monitoring program to sort it for you.

Comment: Your code is correct, but that wouldn't be redirecting based on the file extension, that would be redirecting based off the explicit argument.

Comment: That's what I just explained in the second half. You can't without an external program. That is the only *purely* Ubuntu way.

Comment: I understand that you explained why you said it. But still, it was not what I asked for. I'm not trying to be a dick, just pointing out that your information, while correct and good, is irrelevant. A more helpful thing would be code for a program that constantly checks to see if a file is added to the "downloads" folder, then reroutes it based off its extension. Your answer defines a work-around for the problem, not a solution.